# Understanding proof of the Spectral Theorem in MIT opencourseware notes

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I was looking at the proof of the Spectral Theorem given by MIT opencourseware, found here https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-700-linear-algebra-fall-2013/study-materials/MIT18_700F13_spctrl_thrm.pdf.

It says:

Theorem 1.2 (Spectral theorem). Suppose V is a finite dimensional real
or complex vector space. The linear operator $S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is selfadjoint if
and only if $V$ is the orthogonal direct sum of the eigenspaces of $S$ for real
eigenvalues.

My questions concern only on the $\Leftarrow$ part of the proof, which is left to the reader.

1. If V is a finite dimensional real vector space, how is it guaranteed the existance of eigenvalues?
2. Is the orthogonal condition of the direct sum necessary?

My attempted proof is:

Assume $V$ has k distinct real eigenvalues (I added this assumption since i did not find another way to guarantee the existance of eigenvalues in a real vector spaces). Also assume V equals the direct sum of the k eigenspaces of $S$(i didnt use orthogonality). By proposition 5.41 of Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra done right 3rd edition, i conclude $S$ is diagonalizable. Since the eigenvalues are real, the conjugate transpose of $S$ equals $S$. Thus S is selfadjoint.

Note: Proposition 5.41 gives a series of equivalences which i only show two. It says "Suppose V is finite dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ denote the distinct eigenvalyes of $T$. Then the following are equivalent:

(a) $T$ is diagonalizable

(b) $V=E(\lambda_1,T)\oplus ...\oplus E(\lambda_m,T)$

Ill appreciate your response.

Comment: You seem to say that every diagonalizable matrix with real eigenvalue is selfadjoint... This is not true ! But if the basis of eigenvectors is orthogonal, then it is the case.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you for your reply! Can you please clarify why is it true when the basis of eigenvectors is orthogonal?

Comment: Consider the real case : if $A$ is diagonalizable in an orthogonal basis, then $A=PDP^T$ with $D$ diagonal ; hence $A=A^T$.